# Change value from specific collection

Tags: grid, model

I can get from collection "sales/order" customer ids, but when customer is unregistered, value is "null". What can I do to show in grid which customer is registered, with filter "true" or "false". My code:

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {    
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id');
                foreach($collection as $coll)
                {
                    if ($coll['customer_id'] != '')
                    {
                        $coll['customer_id'] = 'yes';
                    }else{
                        $coll['customer_id'] = 'no';
                    }
                }
    ...

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn("customer_id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("mymodule")->__("Registered"),
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => array(
                        'yes' => 'True',
                        'no' => 'False'
                    ),
                "index" => "customer_id",
            ));
     ...
```

This option was destroy grid filter. Is any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a display value based on customer id (which is pre-maturley loading the collection, having the result that your filters are not applied) you could instead add a new row to the grid based on `customer_is_guest`.

Something like this maybe.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{    
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_is_guest');
...

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn("customer_is_guest", array(
            "header" => Mage::helper("mymodule")->__("Is Guest"),
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => array(
                    'yes' => 'True',
                    'no' => 'False'
                ),
            "index" => "customer_is_guest",
        ));
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use grid renderer function.
See this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298657/magento-admin-grid-column-formatting-renderer).

So basically you are calling a `.php` file for rendering and setting condition to show desired info in there.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:
1) create a file in helper: options.php

```
<?php

namespace MagentoOdoo\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Options extends AbstractRenderer
{
    private $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storemanager, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storemanager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_authorization = $context->getAuthorization();
    }
    /**
     * Renders grid column
     *
     * @param Object $row
     * @return  string
     */
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        if ($this->_getValue($row) == 1) {
            return 'Valid';
        } elseif ($this->_getValue($row) == 2) {
            return 'Invalid';
        } else {
            return 'Undefine';
        }
    }
}
```

2) assign one property for your column:

```
    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
     ...
     $this->addColumn('status',
                 [
                        'header' => __('Status'),
                        'renderer' => '\MagentoOdoo\CustomPro\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Options', 
                        'index' => 'status'
                 ]
                );
     ...
    return $this;
   }
```